# prevent to save back date from validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to write a validation rule that will prevent to store back date.
when i save the record I have given condition is today()+60 now query is suppose any user update the record and change the close date in back date for eg close date is `20/10/2016` if have update the record and change close date in back date link `12/10/2016` or any previous date validation rule fire and throw error message that you cannot save previous date HOW IT IS POSSIBLE FROM VALIDATION RULE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

1. Create a validation rule on that object.
2. In the validation rule add the condition say your field is "close_date__c"
   the condition would be 
   "PRIORVALUE(CloseDate) != CloseDate"
3. Set the error message, message location etc and save

You are done...

Comment: not working this condtion

Comment: Is the data type of close date date time or date?

Answer (score 0):

Add Validation rule
with error condition formula

close_date__c <= TODAY()

and your error message

Comment: Not Working this condtion

Answer (score 0):

I have done

CloseDate < TODAY()+60

Comment: Why to did "TODAY()+ 60" do you want the close date should not be before next 2 months? ?

Comment: in my question when i create new opportunity there is a codntion that close date is today date + 60 when save it its working. now the validation is when i'll go to update record everything can be update except close date. close date cannot be update thats why i give the condition

Comment: I see, you do not want the user to update the at all.  I am updating my answer, please check.